# Visual Studio 2010 using MS Access file

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, ms-access-2007

I am trying to connect to an Access DB file when I do a drag and drop from the dataset to the form i get the following error

[image]
Am I doing it wrong, what should I do ?

```
Dataset not defined
TableAdapter not defined
TableAdapterManager not defined
```

Comment: You might consider copy and pasting the errors into the question. It makes it 1) easier to read and 2) easier to search for

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure what it is you are attempting to accomplish. But working with a database is going be a little more involved than drag and drop. But lucky for you not too much for some situations.

[This website](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/74114-a-really-simple-database/) has a really basic tutorial about working with an access database and a dataset.

[This is a great walk through.](http://www.mltek.co.uk/tips_accessdb_vb.aspx)

[YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-Ga8pXiv6U) also has a lot of videos just search vb.net ms access and Dataset. Should find a few videos to show you step by step.

If this does not help you your going to have to get a little more in detail on what you are trying to do.